# Cell fracture ruins the texture UV

Tags: texturing, uv

Recently I updated blender to the new version (v2.72) and cell fracture not working how expected.
After making box UV and cell fracture for the object the texture become ruined. Maybe there is some new step in newer blender version, or I just forgot something?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the previous version that works for you to compare settings?  If this worked before and not now then it would be a good idea to file a bug report so it can be fixed.

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure I'm using the same settings. I found the same problem already reported: https://developer.blender.org/T42907

Comment: you might want to add your experience to that bug report.  It's poorly formatted with very little information.  The person who originally wrote the code may not even be around to deal with it, so providing as much info as possible helps devs unfamiliar with the area to work on it and to know what's expected of the code from people who have been using it.

Answer (score 5):

I had the exact same problem. I had to remap my texture on all the shards. I did use project from view to unwrap, which should be fairly painless for you if you've just got that cube.

Comment: Is there a way to speed this up, avoiding having to select and do each shard individually?

Comment: I found the command "Edit Mode & Select All & Mesh > UV Unwrap > Project from view" thx!!