# Cell fracture makes textures low res

Tags: texturing, uv

So I have a simple asteroid model I'm trying to fracture with cell fracture, see here:[image: pre-fracture]

However, when I do a cell fracture (default settings), the result looks like this:[image: post-fracture]

But not always! I've gotten it to work twice before, but I have no idea why it worked then and not any other times. Am I missing something obvious? I've spent a couple of days trying to solve this, and I can't find any other threads about it, so I'm totally at a loss.

Assets come from Unity's SpaceShooter demo.

Comment: I imagine that cell fracture is trashing the UV Coordinates.  Most generative tools will damage them.  I'm not sure there is a way around this problem since after using Cell Fracture you now have several new models that all have geometry that was never mapped to the original image.

Comment: No, that's not right, because cell fracture is supposed to retain UV. It actually works properly sometimes (e.g. with a simple cube), but mostly I can't get it to work at all (textures get messed up).

Out of probably a hundred attempts, two have properly retained the UV post-fracture, but I have no idea why.

Comment: as a workaround, try this on each shard "Edit Mode & Select All & Mesh > UV Unwrap > Project from view", tip from [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21062/9567)